# betareg returns values outside of bounds

Tags: r, beta-regression

The `betareg` function returns estimates for `mu` and `phi`. I received the following output for my model:

```
Call:
betareg(formula = VALUE ~ 1, data = example_data)

Standardized weighted residuals 2:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.4461 -0.6925 -0.3335  0.3236  2.9307 

Coefficients (mean model with logit link):
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  4.91608    0.08494   57.88   <2e-16 ***

Phi coefficients (precision model with identity link):
      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(phi)    660.9      176.8   3.739 0.000185 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Type of estimator: ML (maximum likelihood)
Log-likelihood: 126.6 on 2 Df
Number of iterations: 5000 (BFGS) + 4 (Fisher scoring)
```

I am attempting to  transform `mu = 4.9565` and `phi = 56.76` into `a = mu*phi` and `b = (1-mu)*phi`, but I get b < 0 which is out of its bounds.

Granted, my data is very close to 1, but I would think any data within (0,1) should return valid results since this package uses maximum likelihood. Why am I getting values out of range? Am I misinterpreting these coefficients?

```
# Example code
library(betareg)
set.seed(123)
example_data = data.frame(VALUE = rnorm(29,0.993,0.003)) # Very high values in (0,1)

beta_model = betareg(VALUE ~ 1, data = example_data)
mu = summary(beta_model)$coefficients$mean[1] # 4.916083
phi = summary(beta_model)$coefficients$precision[1] # 660.9024
a = mu*phi # 3249.051
b = (1-mu)*phi # -2588.149
```

Comment: What does "rnorm" do? (Are the values in example_data guaranteed to be in (0,1)?)  This has been flagged as off-topic due to being an R programming question. There might be an on-topic conceptual issue involved - could you add a description of what you are doing Something like "I am generating random data from [distribution] and fitting a beta distribution [if that's what is going on here]. The parameter estimates are..."

Comment: @JuhoKokkala rnorm generates random normals. In this case, 29 values with mean 0.993 and sd = 0.003.

Comment: Your data only has one variable (VALUE) so, regression is problematic. You are telling R to fit VALUE as a function of the intercept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mu` as returned by `betareg` is the vector of coefficients of the linear term that has to be run through the inverse link function to get to the original scale.  In your case, since you only have a constant term, the "mu" you want is just the inverse logit transform of 4.916083, i.e., `exp(mu)/(1+exp(mu))`, or 0.9926.

The `precision` is on the identity link scale, so no transform need be made of it.

Comment: You're right that mu seems to be the issue, but I think the logit I need is `exp(4.916083)/(1+exp(4.916083))` = 0.993. As you can see in my code above, that's the mode I expect in my distribution. Thanks! If you edit your answer above I'll accept it.

Comment: I have no idea why I left out the `exp`, just brain damage while typing.  I'll go back and correct it.